# Show to set position of popup?

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have to show popup. I have done it but I am unable to set position of this popup.
I have to set popup at below of friends label.

[image].

Code:

```
_spinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.group_spinner);
_groupAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, _itemGroupList);
_spinner.setAdapter(_groupAdaptor);
_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

And on click I am calling method like:

```
_spinner.performClick();
```

Comment: Can you post your layout code ?

Comment: Can you use a custom dialog or you want it in spinner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem by some correction in layout.
I was doing a silly mistake, Spinner view was not aligned properly.

```
  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/group_text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:text="@string/label_friends"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/dropListImageview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/group_text"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="4dip"
                android:background="@drawable/droplist" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/group_spinner"
                android:layout_width="150dip"
                android:layout_height="20dip"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/group_text"
                android:visibility="invisible"
               />
```

Comment: What is the exact solution here?

Answer (score 0):

Use this my working code..

```
Rect r = locateView(v);    
final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(getActivity());
            popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.animation);
            popup.setContentView(layout);
            popup.setHeight(WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            popup.setWidth(getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth() / 2);
            popup.setFocusable(true);
            popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            popup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT, r.right, r.bottom);


public static Rect locateView(View v) {
        int[] loc_int = new int[2];
        if (v == null)
            return null;
        try {
            v.getLocationOnScreen(loc_int);
        } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            return null;
        }
        Rect location = new Rect();
        location.left = loc_int[0];
        location.top = loc_int[1];
        location.right = loc_int[0] + v.getWidth();
        location.bottom = loc_int[1] + v.getHeight();
        return location;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

I also faced the same problem in my application and found the solution by using spinier. What you have to do just user spinier drop down list in on the click of friends and show your options in that menu. It will help you.

Comment: Why copy paste of user2119025 answer ?

Comment: Flag this answer @GrIsHu

Comment: Actually its my mistake, that is my own id which was created by an mistake i will delete that answer from that id.